# How to switch between folders using keyboard in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Just like we switch to different files using ctrl+p command in Visual Studio Code, Is there any shortcut for switching to different folders in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no shortcut key for it. Yes you can use CTRL+Shift+Q to open the location of selected file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23820862)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: As reference, you can find each shortcut key detail over there. This not who is new here he have never code in life.  Also, check here. www.fiverr.com/ikhan482

Comment: @AndroidNoobie This is an answer. Look at the question - it asks if there are any shortcuts, which this answers

Answer (score 0):

"Ctrl + q" just tipping not holding!
Then you can navigate there with the errows over the files and with "shift + Tab" and Tab over the folders and the menu.

Or you can use "Ctrl + p" or "Ctrl+ e" for the searchmod of all, in the IDE, open/bound project files. Then you can scroll down or type the first letters of the file!

And of course "Alt + f" to open a new or old project/directory.